# getting strings from a database and adding them all together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm writing a code to calculate the length of all the strings combined, adding them together etc collecting them from a database. im unsure how id go about adding them all to a variable and then adding the length to that variable. and also how to display that

```
<h1>Course Rating Information </h1>

<p>
  <strong>Number:</strong>
  <%= @course.number %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Year:</strong>
  <%= @course.year %>
</p> 
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @course.name %>
</p>
<% if @course.comments.exists? %>
  <h2>Ratings</h2>
  <% @course.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <div id='box'>
    <p>
      <strong>Commenter:</strong>
      <%= comment.commenter %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Score:</strong>
      <%= comment.score %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>Comment:</strong>
      <%= comment.comment %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <strong>comment length:</strong>
      <%= comment.comment.length %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= link_to 'Destroy Rating', [comment.course, comment],
        method: :delete,
        data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>

      <%= @charCount =+ comment.comment.length %>


    </p>
  </div>
  </br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br></br>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <h2>No ratings available</h2>
<% end %>

<%= puts #{@charCount} %>

<%= link_to 'New Comment', new_course_comment_path(@course) %>

<%= link_to 'Back to course listing', courses_path %>
```

@charcount is the variable thats supposed to be collecting all the total lengths

Answer (score 2):

You can simple count your total lengths using `inject`:

```
@course.comments.inject(0) { |sum, c| sum + c.comment.length }
```

If you want use your way, you should define `@charCount` before `each` block:

```
@charCount = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

There's more than one way to skin a cat of course. Here, I'd go simply by putting them in an array and summing them:

```
@charCount = @course.comments.map(&:comment).join.length
```